# Checkbox not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i have a checkbox and a textView, when the checkbox is checked, textview should display that checkbox is pressed.
But when i run my code, i get a nullpointerexception.This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CheckBox android=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.android);
    CheckBox ios=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ios);
    CheckBox webos=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.webos);
    CheckBox windows=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.windows);
    Button generate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
    final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked())
                result.setText("Android Checked");
        }
    });

   }
  }
```

and this is the portion of logcat where my problem lies:

```
12-21 17:25:00.324: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(960): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.GridAndroid/com.example.GridAndroid.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.GridAndroid.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

So my question what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6):

get id's after setcontentview()

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

CheckBox android=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.android);
    CheckBox ios=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ios);
    CheckBox webos=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.webos);
    CheckBox windows=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.windows);
    Button generate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
    final TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked())
                result.setText("Android Checked");
        }
    });

   }
  }
```

Comment: It works now, but is it a rule to instantiate all your widgets after the setContentView() method?

Comment: yes only after setContentView is called, the system will know where to find its resource, if not it will simply return null without knowing where to search for the resources.

Comment: yes becouse you can not start your code before attaching your layout.

Answer (score 2):

use your code after this.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```